# Why is data not passed from view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I have a Razor view that lists holiday park accomodations in a table. The user - a park manager - has decided that these should be removed, and now presses the Remove button. The Ids of all of the listed accomodations then must be passed to the controller, but somehow they don't arrive and I cannot lay my finger on why not. Here is the code of the view:

```
@model SunnySideWebManagement.ViewModels.HomeAccomodationsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.PageTitle = "Remove these accomodations?";
    int[] removeIds = new int[Model.Accomodations.Count()];
}

<form asp-controller="home" asp-action="removeaccomodation" asp-route-removeIds="@removeIds" method="post" class="mt-10">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <table id="accomodationsTable" class="row-border">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Id</th><th>Number</th><th>Remarks</th><th>Currently booked</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var ac in Model.Accomodations)
                    {
                        removeIds[index] = ac.Id;
                        index++;
                        <tr><td>@ac.Id</td><td>Number</td><td>@ac.Remarks</td><td>@ac.CurrentlyBooked</td></tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</button>
            <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="accomodations" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I declare an int array *removeIds* and populate it pretty straightforward as the table gets filled. *removeIds* receives the correct values.
The *Remove* button click correctly calls the following code in *HomeController.cs*, as defined in the `<form ...>` element:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RemoveAccomodation(int[] removeIds)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < removeIds.Length; i++)
    {
        _accomodationRepository.Delete(removeIds[i]);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("accomodations");
}
```

A breakpoint here reveals that *removeIds* is an empty array - what happened to its values? What do I overlook, or what do I do wrong?

Comment: you need to declare the route like this `[Route("<ControllerName>/{removeIds:int[]}")]` on top of `RemoveAccomodation` method

Answer (score 0):

Using submit you can only post a view model and nothig else and I don't see any sense in creating removeIds inside of the view, since you are not selecting anything. Since you are using form and submit button , your  whole model will be submitted in any case, doesn't matter if you use asp-route or not. So  remove asp-route-removeIds="@removeIds" and fix the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult RemoveAccomodation(HomeAccomodationsViewModel  model)
{
int[] removeIds = Model.Accomodations.Select(i=> i.Id).ToArray();

 for (int i = 0; i < removeIds.Length; i++)
    {
        _accomodationRepository.Delete(removeIds[i]);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("accomodations");
}
```

PS.

if you want submit only Ids, you have to use an ancor tag, instead of a form, or create a special view model with array of ids. If you want to use ids in ancor,  you have to fill all Ids before creating the ancor, or use javascript. But your code as it is now doesn't make much sense.

PS2

if you still want to return all accomodation items back you have to use for loop instead of foreach loop

```
  @for (var i=0; i <  Model.Accomodations.Count; i++)
 {
                      
 <tr><td>@Model.Accomodations[i].Id</td><td>Number</td>
<td>@Model.Accomodations[i].Remarks</td>
<td>@Model.Accomodations[i].CurrentlyBooked</td></tr>
 }
```

but instead of this you can use just I to get all accomodations from db.

Comment: Yes that makes sense - live 'n' learn I guess. 
Any idea why Accomodations in your `model` parameter might be null though, even though the View displayed several?

Comment: Your suggestion to submit only Ids using an anchor tag works quite nicely - but returning the model makes for more elegant code.

Comment: @Cooz  I updated my answer, see PS2